# java.io.InvalidClassException:

Tags: java, serialization

```
InvalidClassException: local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -196410440475012755, local class serialVersionUID = -6675950253085108747
```

I struct with the InvalidClassException in the following scenario.  Here my EAR is installed in 4 Websphere App servers and execution is shared among this.  Sometimes I got the exception InvalidClassException from POJO class,  Which is implements Serializable interface. Please any clue on this. I don't have any clue regarding to this.

Answer (score 40):

When you implement java.io.Serializable interface to make a class serializable, the compiler looks for a static, final field named "serialVersionUID" of type long. If the class doesn't have this field declared explicitly then the compiler will create one such field and assign it with a value which comes out of a implementation dependent computation of serialVersionUID. This computation depends upon various aspects of the class and it follows the Object Serialization Specifications given by Sun. But, the value is not guaranteed to be the same across all compiler implementations.

This value is used for checking the compatibility of the classes with respect to serialization and this is done while de-serializing a saved object. The Serialization Runtime verifies that the serialVersionUID of the sender class (which was used for saving the state of the object on the stream) and that of the receiver class (the class which is being used to restore the object, possibly at some other system) both are exactly same. If the receiver system has loaded the class having some other serialVersionUID than that of the class used while serialization process then we get an InvalidClassException.

NOTE--
It's highly recommended that you explicitly declare and initialize the static, final field of type long and named 'serialVersionUID' in all your classes you want to make Serializable instead of relying on the default computation of the value for this field. This computation is extremely sensitive and may vary from one compiler implementation to another and hence you may turn up getting the InvalidClassException even for the same class just because you used different compiler implementations on the sender and the receiver ends of the serialization process.

In most of the cases you would be using 'private' access specifier only for this field as the declaration normally applies only to the class declaring it and we don't really need to either inherit this field in the subclasses OR to access it from outside. So, there is hardly any reason why we shouldn't keep it 'private'.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for respond.  As you mention serialization uid is specific to the compiler. But here my compiler version is same in all system and its happening intermittently.

Comment: i am not sure then whats going on... i would recommend you to check the related links available on google and try to relate your code with them. Do comment when u get somthing. (good 2 see somone from banglore, i am from pune.)

Comment: i am facing the same problem right now, does the compiler version mismatch is only reason for this? I have java 1.6.29 and 1.6.23 version on two computers i.e development and release machine

Comment: @Akhilesh Its really difficult to say.But a compiler version mismatch can be a possible case. I would rather recommend you to provide the code and ask it here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - is there any restrictions on what the values ought to be, i.e. can I set them all equal to zero? Also, does anyone know what the purpose of this ID is? Is it to check that the class was decoded correctly? If that's the case, then why should it be so sensitive, i.e. why not just hash the values? I guess where I'm going with this is, is it dangerous for me to override this field? Am I risking bypassing a test for genuine incompatibility between compilers?

Comment: @Alex you can have any value in this id. Please read my answer.

Comment: Better yet, don't use java serialization. There are, like, 50 implementations for marshalling/unmarshalling data. Hell, if you're not using interfaces in these classes (and even then not a big deal) you can serialize it out as JSON adnd back in. The interfaces will give you some more work on trying to marshal as the marshaller needs to know which implementation to use

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno give some example if you can. It will be more helpful.

Answer (score 9):

You get that exception when you try to deserialize an object that was serialized with an incompatible (usually earlier) version of the same class.

If you don't explicitly specify a `serialVersionUID` in your class implementing `Serializable`, then a value will be generated based on the (non-`transient`) fields of your class. This is done to ensure that no partial objects are restored (it's better to fail than to blindly continue with a probably-broken object).

In web-application systems, a common use of serialization is for the session: if you put a value into the session, it's likely that it will be serialized eventually (for clustering support or simply to get persistent sessions).

So *either* keep all your classes compatible between versions *or* ensure that not restoring them does not break your application (i.e. don't store important information this way).

Answer (score 2):

If somebody comes over this issue again in relation to the EJB TimerTask - like I just did - here is a hint if you're using WebSphere Application Server:

There are 2 batch files / shell scripts in the profile's bin folder, which can list and delete the EJB timer tasks. In my case, I had some timer tasks which serialized objects with a different, outdated serialVersionUID. I was't able to get rid of them, since the serialized objects really changed. So I just used those:

findEJBTimers.bat
cancelEJBTimers.bat

Your timer tasks are gone then and so are the error messages. In my case that was exactly what I needed, but it was hard to get this infos.

Answer (score 1):

When an object is serialized, the serialVersionUID is serialized along with the other contents.

Later when that is deserialized, the serialVersionUID from the deserialized object is extracted and compared with the serialVersionUID of the loaded class.

If the numbers do not match then, InvalidClassException is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as asked I will give an example and my piece:

[Here is a list](http://eishay.github.io/jvm-serializers/prototype-results-page/) and performance metrics for various forms of serialization of PoJos

You will have to judge trade offs of performance and convenience. But, since I said 'JSON' as a means of serialization then here is a trivial example that will not be compiler dependent. Basically, unless you changed the structure of your pojo on the receiving end it is completely irrelevant when/how/where you compile it (in fact, it doesn't even have to be between 2 JVMs). As you can see from the link, JSON is actually amongst the slowest and XML is just a payload pig. But both of them have the decisive advantage of being universally supported. XML even allows for the application of style sheets.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Code

```
  @Test
    public void testJSON() throws Exception {
        Foo expected = new Foo(1,"Christian",1000000.00d);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String testJson = gson.toJson(expected);

        System.out.println(testJson);

        Foo result = gson.fromJson(testJson, Foo.class);
        assertEquals(expected,result);

    }

    public static class Foo {

        private String name;
        private Integer age;
        private Double paycheck;

        public Foo(Integer age, String name, Double paycheck) {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.paycheck = paycheck;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            Foo foo = (Foo) o;

            if (age != null ? !age.equals(foo.age) : foo.age != null) return false;
            if (name != null ? !name.equals(foo.name) : foo.name != null) return false;
            if (paycheck != null ? !paycheck.equals(foo.paycheck) : foo.paycheck != null) return false;

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
            result = 31 * result + (age != null ? age.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (paycheck != null ? paycheck.hashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Output

```
{
  "name": "Christian",
  "age": 1,
  "paycheck": 1000000.0
}
```