# java.io.InvalidClassException: oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleNamedType; local class

Tags: java

I am trying to run a script here and it's throwing the below error. I suspect that it's because of the jdk. I am using jdk1.6. I re-complied the script using jdk1.6 and still no solution.

any inputs on this would be a great help!

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleNamedType; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7756018223392232810, local class serialVersionUID = -5293859578141686716
java.io.InvalidClassException: oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleNamedType; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7756018223392232810, local class serialVersionUID = -5293859578141686716
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1315)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ClassTableEntry.readExternal(ClassTableEntry.java:36)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1791)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at weblogic.rjvm.InboundMsgAbbrev.readObject(InboundMsgAbbrev.java:65)
        at weblogic.rjvm.InboundMsgAbbrev.read(InboundMsgAbbrev.java:37)
        at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.readMsgAbbrevs(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.java:283)
        at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.init(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:213)
        at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.dispatch(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.java:498)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.dispatch(MuxableSocketT3.java:330)
        at weblogic.socket.BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.dispatch(BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.java:298)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:950)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:888)
        at weblogic.socket.JavaSocketMuxer.processSockets(JavaSocketMuxer.java:339)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteRequestAdapter.execute(ExecuteRequestAdapter.java:21)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
>
```

Comment: Which driver are you using? I mean, what version?

Comment: Have a look at this link:

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173352/java-io-invalidclassexception

From the logs also it seems like an object is being deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

Seems different class versions in your classpath, the one that is getting deserialized and the one available in your class path are not of the same version.

Comment: I'm using ojdb6 jar.. jdk1.6 version.. I tried by pointing to the same jdk version(1.7.0) to which the server is pointing.. but it didnt work..